# How to get the Url where Grails 3.1.9 integration tests are running?

Tags: grails, grails-3.1

From Grails 3.1.9 relase notes:

> Integration Test Port
>   Integration and functional tests now run on a random port 
>   instead of the same port as the application by default. 
>   This is to avoid port conflict problems when the application 
>   is already running. Integration tests that hard code the port 
>   will need to be altered to use the 
>   serverPort property of tests marked with @Integration

I was normally getting the integration test url with

`import grails.util.Holders
...
..
.
def urlWhereIntegrationAppIsRunning = Holders.grailsApplication.config.grails.serverURL`

Then in my
`application.yml`
I had something like:

`test:
    server:
       port: 8090
    grails:
       serverURL: http://localhost:8090`

How can I get the Url (server url and random port) where my integration test is running with Grails 3.19 inside an integration test?

## Solution

Based on Marco's answer I have done a Trait to encapsulate the url where the integration test run. I implement this trait in the Spock's specifications where I test my API.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value

trait TIntegrationServerUrl {

    @Value('${local.server.port}')
    Integer serverPort

    String integrationServerUrl() {
        "http://localhost:$serverPort"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following in your integration test.

```
@Value('${local.server.port}')
Integer port
```

This will give you the port in the test

Comment: Works as charm.